# Django - select_related does not show the table when trying to convert the object to Json

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

select_related does not show the table when trying to convert the object to Json.

The 'ativacao' table select_related is not shown on print.

```
clientes = Cliente.objects.select_related('ativacao').filter(user=id)
clientes_json = serializers.serialize('json', clientes)
print(clientes_json)
```

Comment: this is not how `select_related` work. It brings the given related models(`ativacao` in your case) and keeps them in the memory so that when you further access the relations it does not query the database and instead pickup from the memory.

Comment: What is `ativacao` in `Cliente` model? a *"reverese-FK"*? and moreover, `select_related` keep a cache that doesn't mean you will have `ativacao` in the resulting JSON

Comment: Django's serializer will only store the Foreign Key(pk of the related field) / natural key if you set them. If you want to serialize related fields you need to customize their serializer. In reality you should really be using something like [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: ativacaois shown when using 'for' and inside the client usage loop. However, only promote the filter, the 'ativacao' table is not shown. He understands?

Comment: Got it. Is there any way I can use it on and force it to be displayed?